# Flink emit event when earlier matching event in pair not found

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have two streams of events: one that emits an event to signal the start of an item's lifetime, and another stream that emits an event to signal the end of an item's lifetime. (The streams can be joined on an `itemId`.)

How can I emit a new event in Flink for each `itemId1` that *only* has an "end of lifetime" event, and not a corresponding beginning? (These beginning and ending events could be hours or days apart.)

Comment: Is it guaranteed in your stream that the "begin of lifetime" event is always before the "end of lifetime" event?
So if you've seen a "eol" event, there won't be a "bol" event anymore.

Comment: Yes, we can assume that the events are always ordered correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the functionality with a stateful `FlatMapFunction` on a `KeyedStream`.

The following code snippet should do pretty much what you are looking for.

```scala
val stream1: DataStream[Event1] = ???
val stream2: DataStream[Event2] = ???

// map both streams to their ID and a isStart flag to have a common type
val ids1: DataStream[(Int, Boolean)] = stream1.map(e => (e.id, true) )
val ids2: DataStream[(Int, Boolean)] = stream2.map(e => (e.id, false) )

// union both streams
val ids = ids1.union(ids2)

// use a stateful FlatMapFunction to check 
val onlyEOL: DataStream[Int] = ids
  // organize stream by ID
  .keyBy(_._1)
  // use stateful FlatMapFunction to check that bol arrived before eol
  .flatMapWithState { 
    (value: (Int, Boolean), state: Option[Boolean]) =>
      if (value._2) {
        // bol event -> emit nothing and set state to true
        ( List(), Some(true))
      } else {
        // eol event
        if (state.isDefined && state.get) {
          // bol was seen before -> emit nothing and remove state
          ( List(), None) 
        } else {
          // bol was NOT seen before -> emit ID and remove state
          ( List(value._1), None)   
        }
      }
  }
```